# I want to print all IP address and hostname from /etc/hosts using Shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, sed

I want to print IP address and hostname from `/etc/hosts` using a shell script

`/etc/hosts` file :

```
## #For example:
## #102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
## #38.25.63.10      x.acme.com              # x client host
## #localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
##  #127.0.0.1       localhost
##  #::1             localhost
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa

# #122.55.80.97     bbb.bb.bb
# #122.55.80.98     ccc.cc.cc
```

I need output valid IP address and host name not all lines

```
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
```

not all the lines

Comment: Which IP address and which hostname? Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve? What have you tried? What results did you expect and what results did you get instead? What kind of errors?

Comment: Hi Filipe, i have list of ipaddress and their hostnames are maintains in /etc/host. Im trying to print (only) ipaddress and hostname  from the hosts file.

Comment: Can you give an example? Such as the contents of your /etc/hosts (or an example, in case you don't want to post the real contents), what is the input, and what you expect as output? It's still unclear what you are trying to do here...

Comment: @KannanM  The `/etc/hosts` file is  usually in `127.0.0.1 localhost` format, IP on left and hostname on right. To print that you just need `cat /etc/hosts`.  This is what we understand, so if this is not what you want - please edit your question and include example of how you want it to look like

Comment: If you want to filter for IPv4 addresses only and get rid of comments and IPv6 stuff, try `grep -E "^([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+" /etc/hosts`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296596/85039

Comment: Personally, I'd say it's sufficient to just do `grep -v '#'`, since the format for the `/etc/hosts` file, at least according to the manual, is only `IP_address canonical_hostname optional_aliasies`. The only other thing that seems to be alright there is comments, which start with `#`. But that's just my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^\s*$/d' /etc/hosts`

will delete all lines starts with # and blank lines.

Comment: It will, however, not deal with comments that does not start at the start of the line, which is a supported type of comment in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 2):

Removing commented out and empty lines form `/etc/hosts`:

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' -e '/^$/d' /etc/hosts
```

This uses three `sed` expressions in the following order:

1. Remove everything after a `#` (including the `#`).
2. Remove blanks (spaces or tabs) at the end of lines.
3. Delete empty lines.

Given your example file, this produces

```
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
111.11.1.1  aaaa.aa.aa
```

This obviously does not try to *validate* the addresses and names that are left.