# How do I use grep to output only the names of files that contain any ipv4 address

Tags: linux, files, grep, ipv4, ip-address

I am using Red Hat Enterprise 6 and I'm trying to search through the /etc/ directory for files that contain any IPv4 address.

Comment: @JeffSchaller im trying to get any ipv4 address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

`grep -lrE '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' /etc`

- -l means list only matching files
- -r is recursive
- -E is extended regex

Regex taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296597/243015