# grep regular expression that matches all valid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Tags: grep, regular-expression, freebsd

I'm looking for a regular expression for `grep` that filters out IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from an arbitrary file containing them. I'd like it to behave like this one for IPv4 addresses:

```bsh
grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
```

I'm aware there are several similar questions with answers here but most focus on just IPv4 addresses and [the best answer I've found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19619/135190) does not work for me. The expression does not output any IP address for me when using `grep`.

As this question is apparently ambiguous, I'm looking for a combined regex. One that will output any valid IP address. As a bonus, even multiple ones on a single line.

If for some reason this is not easy to do with `grep`, I'm open to alternatives, provided they are simple, work on a BSD system and do not require GNU tools.

Comment: This isn't grep, but may be helpful. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192726/verifying-ipv6-addresses/192730

Comment: For IPv4 adresses: [How to check if any IP address is present in a file using shell scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296596/how-to-check-if-any-ip-address-is-present-in-a-file-using-shell-scripting)

Comment: The whole point of my question is a quest for a **combined** expression. What I wonder most is that there's not a simple tool out there to archive this increasingly common task.

Comment: @herrbischoff, if you're looking for a combined expression, you should (have) mention(ed) that in your post. Also, you don't seem to be telling _why_ the solution you linked to "does not work for you". Also, there is some leeway in what is considered a valid IP address, both for IPv4 and for IPv6 (e.g. is `8.8.2056` a valid IPv4 address? Are leading zeroes allowed or should they be normalized away? Must or must not `::` be used in IPv6?). If you want a validating expression, you need to specify what counts a valid.

Comment: This is a common task but _not_ a _simple_ one.  Requiring that it be done with a regular expression makes it quite complex.  Programs generally call `inet_pton()` or equivalent.

Comment: `inet_pton()` requires an already correctly filtered string representation of an IP address and will not extract it itself. It's probably useful for validating but not for extracting/filtering.

Comment: You're not getting the point.  `inet_pton()` does not employ regular expressions.  Employing regular expressions is a restriction that _you_ are imposing, that makes this task complex.

Comment: @JdeBP, but if they do have other text there, with IP addresses intermixed, they'll need some way to pick them out for `inet_pton()` to parse. Be that with regexes or otherwise.

Comment: What is/was your definition of valid? For example 192.168.1.255/24 is arguably a valid IP address - but it's not valid for a host as it's the broadcast address for the specified subnet. In your context valid or not valid?

Comment: Indeed, lets try a more complex regexp grep -Eo '(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative non-`grep`, `perl` based approach using the [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) package (Available as a FreeBSD port under the name `p5-Regexp-Common`):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE 'say $& while /$RE{net}{IPv4}|$RE{net}{IPv6}/g' input.txt
```

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
some words
a line with 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.1 in it.
more words
some line with ::1 in it.
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE 'say $& while /$RE{net}{IPv4}|$RE{net}{IPv6}/g' input.txt
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
::1
```

Comment: The RE for matching a IPv6 address is 3129 characters long, btw.

Comment: "3129 characters..." -- which is kinda what I meant with that comment about an unwieldy regex, though this one seems to have a bunch of unnecessary groups, and could be shortened to just 2200 or so characters ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu It's not unwieldy when you don't have to include it in a script yourself thanks to someone packaging it up for easy use.

Comment: This only outputs the first matching address. I am looking to output **all** matching addresses, as stated in the question.

Comment: @herrbischoff You can have more than one per line?

Comment: I stand corrected: my quick test was indeed a file listing all IPs in one consecutive line. As soon as line breaks are introduced, this appears to work correctly. And I was not asking for matching multiple IPs per line, although it would be nice to have. Thanks!

Comment: @herrbischoff See update for one that works with multiple addresses on one line.

Comment: +1 Works great, thanks. Now, if only the same result could be achieved without installing Perl... I'm not using it for anything else.

Comment: Thanks again for this solution instead of tediously arguing about minor points.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Operating System (FreeBSD) comes with a compiler and a lexer by default (just like any Unix system should), better use them to write a little program, rather than some ass-fugly regexes that nobody will ever be able to understand.

```
$ cat > ipv46.l <<'EOT'
%{
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
%}
W       [0-9A-Za-z_]+
I4      ([0-9]+[.]){3}[0-9]+
I6      ([0-9a-fA-F]|::)[0-9a-fA-F:]*{I4}?
%%
{I6}|{I4} {
        struct in6_addr a6; struct in_addr a; char b[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, yytext, &a6))
                printf("%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &a6, b, sizeof b));
        else if(inet_pton(AF_INET, yytext, &a))
                printf("%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &a, b, sizeof b));
}
{W}|.|\n    ;
EOT

$ lex ipv46.l && cc lex.yy.c -o ipv46 -ll
$ ./ipv46 <file

$ ./ipv46
::0:0:1 1:::1 ::
::1
::
::FFFF:127.0.0.1:80
::ffff:127.0.0.1
...
```

This is rather strict; it will not pull the address `127.0.0.1` from `foo127.0.0.1.12` or `foo:127.0.0.1bar`. But it will be able to pull it from tcpdump's `address.port` form or from the usual `ipv4:port`, and it will be able to handle "mixed" ipv4/ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works quite well, although it is very strict, as you say. I just tested it on a tcpdump excerpt and it couldn't make out any IP address in a line containing `block in on vtnet0: 213.109.234.47.19888 > 213.109.163.124.23`. Is there possibly a modification that is able to read that format?

Comment: I've updated to a version which should handle the `host.port` thing (Which aren't actually valid ipv4 or ipv6 addresses). But this is less robust than simply tokenizing words of `[a-zA-Z0-9_:.]+` and applying `inet_pton` to them.

Comment: Anyways, this was one of the xyest xy-questions ;-) You should've started with telling that's a tcpdump output, not an arbitrary file. It's unlikely that those addresses need any validation, something simple like `awk '/ > /{print$10; print $12}' file | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` could've done.

Comment: I’ve not led with that because the tcpdump file is just an extreme example. I was looking for a general solution, not super-specific to one use case. If it were just those logs, writing even a regex would be quite straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

This should extract the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```bash
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}'
```

However, it does not check that the IPv6 addresses are truly valid as they could contain more than 1 `::`.

Comment: This regex also accepts invalid IPv4 addresses, such as when one or more of the octets are greater than 255. It is also very unusual to do this but try `ping 2130706433` .

Answer (score -1):

This should do the error checking for IPv4 and is more compact

```shell
grep -Eo '([0-255]\.){3}[0-255]|([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}'
```

Comment: As far as I know, `[0-255]` will not accept any number between 0 and 255, but will accept digits 0, 1, 2 and 5.